# How do I get my Intel dual band wireless AC 7260 WIFI Card to work with Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I’m quite new to Linux, and am not sure how to go about getting this to work.

I’m not sure how to get my Toshiba Satellite E55-A5114’s WIFI Card to Work ([Computer info](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/E50/E55-A5114)).

While in Windows 8.1, I was able to figure out that I have an Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260 WIFI Card by clicking on This Computer—> Device Manager—> Network Adapters.

I did some searching with Google, and found these page from Intel’s Linux Drivers/Downloadss:

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=17045

So, using those pages as guidelines, can someone tell me exactly what I should type into the Terminal in order to get my WIFI work work?

I'm not certain which distro I'm going to use, I'm downloading a number of different ones to see which I like best.  Some of them are Apt-based, others RMP-based and still others are Pacman-based; I don't think any of them are Yum-based, however I do believe that Yum is available in a number of different ones I'm going to try.  If there are different Terminal commands to be used for each of those, please tell me how I could get it to work depending on which packaging-system they use.

If you're wondering, here are the distros I'm going to try:

snowlinux-4-glacier-amd64.iso deepin_2013.1_en_amd64.iso

kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso linuxmint-16-kde-dvd-64bit.iso

Mageia-4-x86_64-DVD.iso openSUSE-13.1-DVD-x86_64.iso

archlinux-2014.06.01-dual.iso OpenMandrivaLx-2014.0.x86_64.iso

antergos-2014.06.14-x86_64.iso

debian-live-7.5.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso

elementaryos-stable-amd64.20130810.iso

Like I said, I’m relatively new to Linux, especially when it comes to getting hardware to work.  So whatever help you can provide me will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Have you actually tried yet? The Intel WiFi driver is an in-kernel driver. Any recent distro would have it available out of the box.

Comment: When I loaded Elementary OS, for instance, it did not show any options for WIFI at all.

Comment: Well, the shipped kernel (3.2) in the current version of Elementary OS is simply way too old. Support for your card is available from 3.10 onwards, as stated on the `iwlwifi` info page. A more up-to-date distribution like Arch Linux might yield better results.